# Jasper Report to show lots of static text

Tags: ms-word, jasper-reports

Can anyone suggest a way around this problem with my JasperReport ?  I am using iReport 4.4.1 to write a report that also contains a lot of static contractual text, which I am putting in a text box in the Jasper template.

When rendered into rtf, and read in MS Word,  the text box correctly starts half way down the first page,  and another different text box appears at the top of the second page.  All the text in both boxes is correct.

But when I insert lines at the top of the text box on the first page,  the overflow at the bottom does not move onto the box on the second page,  it just disappears.

Really I just want the text to go straight into the Word document,  not within a text box.

Am I missing something ?

The sample of the report:

```xml
<jasperReport xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="259"/>
    <queryString language="xPath">

    </queryString>
    <field name="para1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription>/study/para1</fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="5" y="10" width="540" height="512"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression>$F{para1}</textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: What split type has your band? What stretch type has your text box? Is "strech with overflow" enabled for text box?

Comment: I did have a second band with a stretch type of default,  thanks for mentioning that,  I was focused on the text box.

Comment: Alex,The band has split type stretch.  Text Box has Stretch Type of Relative to Band Height and Text box also has stretch with OverFlow.  If I add text to the top of the text box,  words at the bottom become hidden because they are truncated.  I would love a way just to put the text straight into the document.  By the way,  I'm exporting as RTF and using Word 2003 to open it in an IE 7 browser.  Thanks for your suggestions anyway.

Comment: Can you post your template (may be light version)? I can try it

Comment: Sorry to have not replied for so long,  here is an example.  Thanks. [link](http://www.guyroberts.co.uk/jasper_issue.xml)

Comment: The core problem is that text in the Word document is bounded by an invisible box instead of being in the flow of the whole document !  So if anybody edits the start of it,  text is pushed down and eventually disappears.

Comment: Jasper creates a table in Word and all fields go into that.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the **`net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.flexible.row.height`** property to the report with the **`true`** value.

The sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ...>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.flexible.row.height" value="true"/>
```

More information about this property is [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.flexible.row.height).